Dockerizing django app with Nginx, gunicorn and docker-compose - data base connectivity issue
Amateur programer here. I usually can google my way out of every issue but I struggle with the huge diversity in set ups for docker (and honestly feel al ittle overwhelmed). I am aware the the biggest tutorials out there (including the famous digitalocean one), but it didn't help.
As title says, I am trying to dockerize a django app (in order to deploy to a VPS) using Nginx en gunicorn.
My docker-compose file has a data base service, a django_unicorn service and a nginx container.
The data base and nginx containers seem to set up correctly. But when my django_unicorn runs, in fails to connect to the data base.
The error message is :

django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")]

After a while, it stops and gives me the localhost server to connect to, but it obviously shows nothing.
I tried checking on the data base within my docker container. It is working fine and I connect within it with root user and my custom user. I uses the exact same credentials in my settings.py file in django. The HOST and PORT look ok to me (referring the db service in docker-compose and using port 3306 like in docker-compose.
I really want to manage to run this locally and maybe soon switch to a VPS.
My folder organisation :
whatsthefit

.venv
conf


_pycache




gunicorn_config.py


nginx


default.conf




Dockerfile


whatzthefit


App1




App2


manage.py
requirements.txt
dockerignore
.env
.gitignore
docker-compose.yml
Dockerfile
entrypoint.sh

List item
My set up files :
the docker-compose file
version: "3.7"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:oraclelinux8
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASS}
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - "3306"
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost", "-u", "${DB_USER}", "-p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 3

  django_gunicorn:
    volumes:
      - static:/static
    env_file:
      - /home/ynot/fitweb/whatzthefit/.env
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db


  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static:/static
      - media:/media
    ports:
      - "84:84"
    depends_on:
      - django_gunicorn


volumes:
  static:
  data:
  media:

NGINX
default.conf file
upstream django {
    server django_gunicorn:8080;
}

server {
    listen 84;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /static;
    }

    location /media/{
        alias /media;
    }
}

** nginx Dockerfile**
FROM nginx:1.25.4-alpine-slim

COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

Main dockerfile
FROM nginx:1.25.4-alpine-slim

# replace the nginx default conf by the one we made in this folder
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/sh

python manage.py migrate --noinput
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

gunicorn fitweb.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000

gunicorn_config.py
import os

command = "/home/ynot/fitweb/whatzthefit/.venv/bin/gunicorn"
pythonpath = "/home/ynot/fitweb/whatzthefit/whatzthefit"
bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"
workers = 3

Thanks you in advance for your help. I'm sorry for the code dumping, but I hope it makes the issue easier to find.

If you are trying to connect your MySQL database in docker compose, try using links options in docker-compose.yml.
Using links, it means that the container can search other container which is linked.
As below, you can add link to db in django-gunicorn service:
django_gunicorn:
volumes:
  - static:/static
env_file:
  - /home/ynot/fitweb/whatzthefit/.env
build:
  context: .
ports:
  - "8080:8080"
depends_on:
  - db
links:
  - db

As name of linked service is db, you can just use db as hostname.
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '<DB_NAME>',
        'USER': '<DB_USER>',
        'PASSWORD': '<DB_PASS>',
        'HOST': 'db',  # Linked docker name
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


Thanks for the suggestion. It's not doing anything for me juste adding it. But I'll look deeper into this option.
